# Error Response from OBD-ii (7F 01 11)

Tags: obd-ii, elm327

I have been extracting OBD-II DATA from UART board (ELM327) on my TOYOTA INNOVA. It responded correctly few weeks before and gave all supported sensor values. But now, for every response, ECU responds **"7F 01 11"**. Please tell me what exactly this output means and how to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Hi, was it full like this:
Get Data From id: 0x7E9
0x3 0x7F 0x1 0x11 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x
did it started from 0x03? i am getting this always when requesting for supported pids and dint find an answer

Answer (score 1):

7F is the general fail response.

11 means: Service Not Supported.

So that is what it means. However it seems strange as it was working before.
Did you change any setting of the ELM327 module? If so, it could be possible to reset all settings.

Source: http://blog.perquin.com/prj/obdii/

Comment: Yes we did change the module settings like header through AT SH and few other settings but then we reset it through ATZ/ATD but still the same problem persists. How can we completely reset it to get it working as before. Also, we have been trying very hard to contact you regarding some queries related to OBD-II and serial communication so is there any way we can contact you personally ?

Comment: I don't know if I can help you then. Was about to suggesting ATZ & ATD, but if that doesn't work I don't know a answer without trying myself. You can find more information to contact me at: https://github.com/EricSmekens/node-serial-obd/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Try ATSP0 to reset the protocol to AUTO, then use a commonly supported "0100" command to see if the OBD-II compliant ECUs respond.